# Applying afilter () function to multiple files before calculating ACI

Tags: r

I need to calculate Acoustic Complexity Index (ACI) of hundreds of .wav files as part of a Soundscape Ecology study.

The soundecology package in R has a very useful function multiple_sounds () function. However, I couldn't find any amplitude filter in the package.

seewave package has afilter () which allows to set filtering of amplitude by setting at certain thresholds.

I would like to use afilter () to many .wav files in a folder and then to apply multiple_sounds () to all the filtered files. Since I am new to R, I am at a loss to combine or loop these two functions to get desired results.

Can you please help me in this?

Examples:

```
afilter (.wav files,f=22050,threshold= 5,plot= F)

multiple_sounds (directory = "C:/Users/pc1/Desktop/sound",
            resultfile = "C:/Users/pc1/Desktop/sound/results1.csv",
            soundindex = "acoustic_complexity",min_freq = 1500, max_freq = 
            12000, j = 5, fft_w = 512)
```

Thank you,

Ana

Answer (score 0):

Here's some code that might help you to get going.

```
library(soundecology)
library(seewave)
library(tuneR)

# make some wav files
w1 = sawtooth(440, duration = 20, xunit = 'time')
writeWave(w1, "w1.wav")
w2 = noise(kind='white', duration = 20, xunit = 'time')
writeWave(w2, 'w2.wav')

# find the wav files
wavfiles = list.files(pattern='wav')

# a function to be called for each wav
processWav = function(wavfile) {
    wav = readWave(wavfile)
    wav.filtered = afilter(wav, threshold = 5, plot = F, output = 'Wave')
    wav.aci = acoustic_complexity(wav.filtered)
    wav.aci
}

# apply the function to all the wavs
result = sapply(wavs, function(wav) processWav(wav))

result
#                      w1.wav      w2.wav     
#AciTotAll_left        1783.374    600.5361   
#AciTotAll_right       NA          NA         
#AciTotAll_left_bymin  5350.12     1801.61    
#AciTotAll_right_bymin NA          NA         
#aci_fl_left_vals      Numeric,256 Numeric,256
#aci_fl_right_vals     Logical,4   Logical,4  
#aci_left_matrix       List,4      List,4     
#aci_right_matrix      List,4      List,4
```

I didn't use the `multiple_sounds` function because it would have necessitated reading the wav files, filtering them and writing them out again which felt like too much processing. Generally, the `sapply` function works very quickly.